# Swift: index(of:) doesn't exist?

Tags: swift

I keep trying to use index(of:) on Array objects but it doesn't come up in the autocomplete (or whatever that menu is called) and, of course, doesn't build. I see it right there in the documentation! It's there! I want it! What's going on here?

(Btw this isn't the only Array method I can't access. For just one example, I can't use suffix(from:), I can only use suffix(maxLength:), plus it's implemented as suffix(_ maxLength:) even though the documentation lists it as requiring an argument name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is only available on array where the elements conforms to the equatable protocol. If this is true and you still don't have this method available please check that you are using Swift 3 and not an old version of Swift.

Example that will not work:

```
struct NotEquatable {}

let first = NotEquatable()
let second = NotEquatable()

[first, second].index(of: second) // Will not work
```

Example that will work:

```
struct IsEquatable: Equatable { 
    let word: String 
}

let first = IsEquatable(word: "First")
let second = IsEquatable(word: "Second")

[first, second].index(of: second) // Will return 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let array = [1, 2, 7, 9]

let index = array.index(of: 2)
```

this prints 1 in playground swift 3, which swift version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of swift you are using. If 2.3 f.e. some of methods won't be called the way they are in swift 3. You need to search for proper swift version.